# Como fazer uma navbar com duas logomarcas?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou precisando fazer uma navbar que recebe duas brands, uma ao lado da outra

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="col-md-3 navbar-nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="/assets/img/logo1.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 navbar-nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="/assets/img/logo2.png" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
    </div>    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tools" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tools">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#"><i class="fas fa-desktop text-center"><br><span class="text-center  lead">Monitoramento</span></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#"><i class="far fa-comments text-center"><br><span class="text-center  lead">Fórum</span></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#"><i class="far fa-envelope text-center"><br><span class="text-center  lead">Contato</span></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Essas logos não podem ficar muito pequenas, de modo que quando chegar na versão mobile, é preciso ter uma quebra de linha ficando uma logo acima e outra baixo. Como no exemplo abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que preciso que o botão do toggle fique a direita, no meu código quando quebra pra versão mobile o botão do toggle está decendo pra linha de baixo. Outro problema é que na versão tablet a segunda brand está ficando centralizada, gostaria que ficasse uma do lado da outra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta colocar as duas logos dentro de um `span`, nesse `span` vc vai usar as classe de flex nativas do Bootstrap para controlar o posicionamento das logo. Quando for em telas pequenas vc vai colocar `d-flex` e `flex-column` no `span` e vc vai ter esse comportamento como na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <span class="d-flex flex-column d-sm-inline">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar1</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar2</a>
        </span>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#"><i class="fas fa-desktop text-center"><br><span class="text-center  lead">Monitoramento</span></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#"><i class="far fa-comments text-center"><br><span class="text-center  lead">Fórum</span></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#"><i class="far fa-envelope text-center"><br><span class="text-center  lead">Contato</span></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```